# how to centralize log4j2 configuration with Spring Cloud Config Server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, log4j2, spring-cloud-config

I'm using Spring Cloud Config Server File System Backend : [docs.spring.io](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/server/environment-repository/file-system-backend.html)

I have a multi maven project

```
project:
├── pom.xml
│
├── project-config-provider
│   ├── pom.xml
│   ├── src
│   │   └── main
│   │       ├── java
│   │       │   └── com
│   │       │       └── company
│   │       │           └── project
│   │       │               └── config_provider
│   │       │                   └── Application.java
│   │       └── resources
│   │           └── log4j2-spring.yaml
│   │
│   │
│   ├── config
│   │   ├── application_config-provider--native.yaml
│   │   └── application_config-provider--aws.yaml
│   │
│   └── cloud_config
│       ├── application-config_main.yaml
│       ├── application-config_storage.yaml
│       ├── application-config_swagger.yaml
│       └── application-env_local.yaml
│
│
└── project-abc
    ├── pom.xml
    ├── src
    │   └── main
    │       ├── java
    │       │   └── com
    │       │       └── company
    │       │           └── project
    │       │               └── abc
    │       │                   └── AbcApplication.java
    │       └── resources
    │           └── log4j2-spring.yaml
    │ 
    └── config
        └── application_abc.yaml
```

---

The module `project-config-provider` is the spring cloud config server,
and the module `project-abc` will use some of the configs from project-config-provider.

each module has a `config` folder:

- the project-config-provider contains multiple yaml files, one for each environment (application_config-provider--native.yaml for local test, application_config-provider--aws.yaml for aws test with secretmanager and S3)

application_config-provider--native.yaml :

```
spring:
   application:
      name: config-provider
   profiles:
      active: native
      include: config_main
   cloud:
      config:
         server:
            native:
               search-location: cloud_config
            prefix: /config
            bootstrap: true

server.port: 8888
```

- all the other modules has only one yaml file

application_abc.yaml :

```
spring:
   application:
      name: maps
      version: 1.0.0
   profiles:
      #declare the configurations to include from cloud_config folder of config-provider 
      include: config_main, config_storage, config_swagger
   config:
      import: configserver:http://${CONFIG_PROVIDER_HOST:localhost}:${CONFIG_PROVIDER_PORT:8888}/config
```

I want to move the log4j2-spring.yaml under cloud_config folder, so it will be centralized, and I don't have to duplicate it for each maven module of the project.

The issue is that it seems to be required to be in the src/main/resources.

Comment: Can't you create a shared project (java library), and import it that way?

Comment: yeah, why not, I didn't think about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Spring Cloud Config for your application configuration then it makes perfect sense to use it for the log4j configuration as well. To do this you would usually configure your application's bootstrap.yml with something like:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: abc
  cloud:
    config:
    uri: https://spring-configuration-server.company.com/
```

To add the logging configuration you need to add log4j-spring-boot-n.n.n.jar as a dependency of your application and then add

```
  logging
    config: "https://spring-configuration-server.company.com/log4j2.xml"
```

The path of to the file depends on how your SCC service is configured to search for files.

By default, the only remote protocol allowed for loading
configuration files is HTTPS. If you need to enable HTTP, you should also add

```
log4j2.Configuration.allowedProtocols: "http,https"
```

If you want the logging configuration to automatically update you can either configure your SCC to generate events to Spring Cloud Bus and then configure your app to receive them by adding the log4j-spring-cloud-client jar and configuring Spring Cloud Bus in your app to receive the events sent by the SCC service or you can configure Log4j to poll for changes by specifying